# /* and /** for javadoc - just Eclipse or is this a Java convention?

Tags: java

I noticed that in Eclipse when I use

```
/*
 * My Comment
 */
public class myClass {

}
```

"My Comment" does not associate with the class but

```
/**
 * My Comment
 */
public class myClass {

}
```

"My Comment" does

Similarly

```
/** myComment */
public static final String MY_VARIABLE = "testing";
```

also associates with the javadoc.

Is this a Eclipse thing or part of the java documenting system.

Should I always use /** as opposed to /* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* My Comment */    is usually used for making a comment block.

/** MyComment */    is usually used for documentation purposes, such as desribing variables and things like that.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is how [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/) wants the comments and Javadoc is the  de-facto industry standard. ([Sun's How to write Doc Comments](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/))

Other tools such as doxygen also support the Javadoc style, so you should always use `/**` for comments documenting a class, method or variable when developing in Java unless there is a good reason otherwise. For general comments `/*` should be used

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `/**` to associate it; not `/*`. Thanks

**[More Information Here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/)**